# Define HTML Map Tip using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

using PyQGIS, I need to create a map tip using this HTML code: `ID = [% ID %]` and style it like the picture below (white text and black background). I don't know how to use CSS in this case.

If is not possible create a map tip using PyQGIS, can I maybe save it in a .qml file e set it using PyQGIS in someway?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set some CSS in your maptip and using PyQGIS too:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

expression = """
<style>
html *{
background-color: black ;
color: white;
}
</style>

Name : [% "nom" %]
"""
layer.setMapTipTemplate(expression)
```

PS : I'm trying to remove the white border line.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. P.s. I know that this is another question, but do you know if you can reduce map tips delay using PyQGIS? Thanks again

Comment: `QgsSettings().setValue('qgis/mapTipsDelay', 500)`. Be careful, this is a QGIS user setting.